# I don't understand the Hollywood Principle

Tags: java, inversion-of-control

sorry for my English.

I stumble upon this principle when reading the "Head First Design Patterns" book. I see other peoples ask on StackOverFlow the same question and a few articles but I still don't understand it.

Can someone explain it in the simplest term for me?

Most of the example I've read is assuming that the reader already uses a framework supporting IoC like Spring. I never use those frameworks before because I'm still a beginner.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the book mention the phrase "Don't call us, we'll call you"?

Comment: @Kevin Anderson Yes!

Comment: The "Hollywood" connection is that "Don't call us; we'll call you" is allegedly the standard polite-but-unmistakable phrase of dismissal used in show business.  It's kind of a standard joke: aspiring actor steps to the stage, introduces himself and begins his audition; ten seconds in, casting director pipes in with "Thank you, that will be all. Don't call us; we'll call you.  NEXT!".

Answer (score 5):

It's been a while but due to the number of viewers, i explain it.

**The Hollywood** Principle which sometimes referred to as **Inversion of Control** says "Don't call us, we'll call you" Which in terms of software engineering it states that an object which depends on another one should not call it but should wait for the other to call it.

This principle defines the IOC with more abstraction. As you know IoC defines  inversing the control of dependencies. So first of all you should have a control center responsible for controlling dependencies i.e for making instance of them. This control center then inverses the flow of making instance of classes. So when you want to use *ClassA* in *ClassB*, you won't create instance of *ClassB* then Call *ClassA*. You make instance of *ClassA* and pass it to *ClassB* using different techniques and use it.

For more information about IoC have some invest on the internet as i just explained some basic concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at the "library vs framework" ambiguity problem. Here's one of the article found in Google search: [The Difference Between a Framework and a Library](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/framework-vs-library).

**In short:** A *library* is called by our program (so **we** call the library when **we** need it); a *framework* calls our program's fragments when **it** needs this.